# stringbuilder to not escape curly brackets

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm using JSON to get a System.Net.WebResponse then reading the response into a StringBuilder before getting the result of the response by calling the StringBuilder.ToString() method. I can't Parse such a respsone using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(repsonse);

My problem is that the ToString() method is removing my '{' and '}' characters because they get escaped unless matched with another '{'. Even if I do a StringBuilder.Replace("{", "{{") It doesn't work because the final brackets escape the first brackets --> Example below

My code for getting the response is:

```
public static string GetResponseFromRequest(string url){       

        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        byte[] read = new byte[256];
        int count = res.GetResponseStream().Read(read, 0, 256);
        while (count > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(read));
            count = res.GetResponseStream().Read(read, 0, 256);
        }
        res.GetResponseStream().Close();

        res.Close();

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Here is a sample of what my response looks like:

```
{{ 
"id" : "myID",
"Name" : "MyDisplayName",
"description" : "A, MyDescription",
}"hasOverview" : true,
"hasDescription" : true,
  }
```

AFTER StringBuilder.ToString is called it looks like this:

```
 "{ 
    "id" : "myID",
    "Name" : "MyDisplayName",
    "description" : "A, MyDescription",
   }"hasOverview" : true,
    "hasDescription" : true,
      "
```

If I call StringBuilder.Replace("{", "{{") and StringBuilder.Replace("}", "}}") I get:

```
"{{ 
    "id" : "myID",
    "Name" : "MyDisplayName",
    "description" : "A, MyDescription",
   }}"hasOverview" : true,
    "hasDescription" : true,
      "
```

I need a way to tell ToString() to return a literal representation of what the string builder is holding so it doesn't take special characters into account. If possible just the '{' and '}' characters in particular.

Comment: StringBuilder doesn't modify characters, ever.

Comment: @JohnSaunders well it does if you use the AppendFormat method (to replace the formatting placeholders, which it looks like the OP is running into).  But I've got to assume that the OP is not doing that.

Comment: StringBuilder wouldn't escape brackets. How do you know what the response looks like BEFORE `StringBuilder.ToString` is called?  Are you sure you haven't taken out some relevant parts of the code in your example?

Comment: And apologies if that came across as snarky- I was nitpicking above :-)  I only say "I assume..." because the OP's code does not compile as posted (no return statement in `GetResponseFromRequest`), and so I assume it was redacted somehow, and maybe we were not seeing the real problem.

Comment: @ChrisShain That wasn't snarky. It is meant to be "return sb.ToString(); That's a pretty bad typo so I will fix it.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I can put a breakpoint in and see the 'sb' as a string. Then I can check the value returned by ToString() the same way. They are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disproved your original assumption by doing the following:

```
public static void TestSB()
{
    var testValue = "{{ \"id\" : \"myID\", \"Name\" : \"MyDisplayName\", \"description\" : \"A, MyDescription\", }\"hasOverview\" : true, \"hasDescription\" : true, }";
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(testValue);
    var sbToString = sb.ToString();

    // Prints true
    Console.WriteLine(sbToString.Equals(testValue));
}
```

So with that out of the way, I think the problem is that you are trying to convert the text 256 bytes at a time, and mangling characters in the process.  There are classes in the framework designed for the task you are attempting to accomplish, namely reading text from a Stream.  Try this instead:

```
public static string GetResponseFromRequest(string url)
{
    var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (var res = req.GetResponse())
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I tested this using the following method and the result looks OK:

```
public static void TestGetResponse()
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetResponseFromRequest("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

EDIT:

Or better yet,

```
var result = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url)
```

Comment: You are correct. Appending them bit by bit causes the problem I was having with the removal of the curly braces. Also thanks for the pointer to the WebClient class. It's a lot better to work with.